# buserror given by quickfix

Tags: c++, solaris, quickfix

I was trying to get a simple demo quickfix program to run on solaris, namely http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429147/The-FIX-client-and-server-implementation-using-Qui   prior to getting it to do what I want it to.

unfortunately in main the application gives a bus error when

```
FIX::SocketInitiator initiator( application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);
```

is called
examine the core dump with gdb and I see

```
(gdb) where
#0  FIX::SessionFactory::create (this=0xffbfee90, sessionID=@0x101fe8, settings=@0x100e34)
at FieldConvertors.h:113
#1  0xff2594ac in FIX::Initiator::initialize (this=0xffbff108) at stl_tree.h:246
#2  0xff25b270 in Initiator (this=0xffbff108, application=@0xffbff424, 
messageStoreFactory=@0xffbff1c4, settings=@0xffbff420, logFactory=@0xffbff338)
at Initiator.cpp:61
#3  0xff25f8a8 in SocketInitiator (this=0xffbff108, application=@0xffbff3c8, 
factory=@0xffbff388, settings=@0xffbff408, logFactory=@0xffbff338) at SocketInitiator.cpp:52
#4  0x0004a900 in main (argc=2, argv=0xffbff4c4) at BondsProClient.cpp:42
```

So I look in FieldConverters.h and we have the code

```
inline char* integer_to_string( char* buf, const size_t len, signed_int t )
{
    const bool isNegative = t < 0;
    char* p = buf + len;

    *--p = '\0';

    unsigned_int number = UNSIGNED_VALUE_OF( t );

    while( number > 99 )
    {
        unsigned_int pos = number % 100;
        number /= 100;
        p -= 2;
        *(short*)(p) = *(short*)(digit_pairs + 2 * pos);
    }

    if( number > 9 )
    {
        p -= 2;
        *(short*)(p) = *(short*)(digit_pairs + 2 * number);  //LINE 113 bus error line
    }
    else
    {
        *--p = '0' + char(number);
    }

    if( isNegative )
        *--p = '-';

    return p;
}
```

Looking at this I'm actually not surprised this crashes. It's de-referencing a char* pointer passed to the function as a short, without checking the alignment, which can't be known. This is illegal to any C / C++ standard and since the sparc processor can't perform an unaligned memory access, the thing obviously crashes. Am I being really thick here, or is this a stone cold bug of massive proportions in the quickfix headers? quickfix IS (according to their website) supposed to compile and be usable on solaris sparc. Does anyone know of any work around for this? The option of edit thew header to sprintf springs to mind, as does aligning some things. Or is the a red herring with something different causing an unaligned buffer?

Comment: I'm quite convinced this is but the tip of the iceberg for this code. Aka. `p-=2` for example. the assumption `sizeof(short) == 2` isn't exactly healthy. If paranoia really sets in you can always pull out the two octets yourself and assembly the short.

Comment: Also, looking at this, I'm also thinking that although gcc is usually nice about not giving unaligned memory, `*--p = '\0'` is going to virtually guarantee an unaligned pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's crashing due to misaligned loads/stores then you could replace lines such as:

```
*(short*)(p) = *(short*)(digit_pairs + 2 * number);
```

with a safer equivalent using memcpy:

```
memcpy((void *)p, (const void *)(digit_pairs + 2 * number), sizeof(short));
```

Comment: true, This is not quite what I had in mind for the header of a library though. I'm currently thinking bug report time

Comment: Sure - either way this code needs to be fixed - regardless of alignment issues, the `*(short*)p` type punning breaks strict aliasing rules and may generate bad code with some compilers/optimisation settings - maybe now, maybe in the future...

Comment: I'm accepting, since making this modification to the header, and since the header is called internally re-compiling the entire quickfix library in addition to the demo application itself got the test application to actually work.